# Can't map a viewgroup children

Tags: android, kotlin

Why map isn't working in this viewgroup chieldren list?

```
class DivisorItem(context: Context): RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
private val mDivisor: Drawable? = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.item_divisor)

override fun onDrawOver(c: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
    val left = parent.paddingLeft
    val right = parent.width - parent.paddingRight

    parent.children.map {
        val params = it.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
        val top = it.bottom + params.bottomMargin
        val bottom = top + mDivisor!!.intrinsicHeight
        mDivisor.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom)
        mDivisor.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        mDivisor.draw(c)
    }

}
}
```

There is 4 views in this viewgroup but it never enter in map block

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Added the entire class... this is a divider for a RecyclerView

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution... parent.children is sequence

I opened the source and found it:

```
val ViewGroup.children: Sequence<View>
get() = object : Sequence<View> {
    override fun iterator() = this@children.iterator()
}
```

I think it is unmutable... above this code in the same source I found

```
operator fun ViewGroup.iterator() = object : MutableIterator<View> {
private var index = 0
override fun hasNext() = index < childCount
override fun next() = getChildAt(index++) ?: throw IndexOutOfBoundsException()
override fun remove() = removeViewAt(--index)
```

}

So I changed my code to:

```
parent.iterator().forEach {
        val params = it.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
        val top = it.bottom + params.bottomMargin
        val bottom = top + mDivisor!!.intrinsicHeight
        mDivisor.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom)
        mDivisor.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        mDivisor.draw(c)
    }
```